# Add AJAX to Webform select option

Tags: entities, ajax

I want to add ajax event to the following code

```
function dataoption_field_webform_select_options_info() {

  $items = array();

  $items['clienti'] = array(
    'title' => t('Clienti'),
    'options callback' => '_getClienti',
  );

  $items['periferiche'] = array(
    'title' => t('Periferiche'),
    'options callback' => '_getPerif',
  );

  return $items;
}

function _getClienti(){
   $result=db_query("select NomeCliente from ProvaClienti");
   $options = array();
   $count = 0;
     while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()){
        $options[$count]=t($row['NomeCliente']);    
        $count++;       
     }
   return $options; 
 }

 function _getPerif(){
    $result=db_query("select periferica from periferiche where cliente='AAAAAAAA'");
    $options = array();
    $count = 0;
      while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()){
        $options[$count]=t($row['periferica']); 
        $count++;       
      }
    return $options;    
  }
```

At change of first select option I want to change values of second select option. So I must pass a variable (the value of first select) to `function _getPerif` and than change value of second select.

I'm working with *Webform Module*. Anyone can help me?

Thanks